# Nativescript Angular - Hide shadow on Android Tabs

Tags: android, tabs, nativescript, shadow

I have the next code:

```
    <ActionBar title="Tabs" flat="true" backgroundColor="white"></ActionBar>
    <StackLayout class="page" >
        <Tabs selectedIndex="0">
            <TabStrip highlightColor="#ff2e63" backgroundColor="white">
                <TabStripItem>
                    <Label text="Tab1" fontSize="15"></Label>
                </TabStripItem>
                <TabStripItem>
                    <Label text="Tab2" fontSize="15"></Label>
                </TabStripItem>
            </TabStrip>

            <TabContentItem>
                <Card:CardView elevation="0" radius="0">
                    <Label class="fa" flexGrow="1" text="&#xf362;"></Label>
                </Card:CardView>
            </TabContentItem>

            <TabContentItem>
                <Card:CardView elevation="0" radius="0">
                    <Label class="fa" flexGrow="1" text="&#xf362;"></Label>
                </Card:CardView>
            </TabContentItem>
        </Tabs>
    </StackLayout>
```

For design reasons I want that the tabs on Android don't have the bottom shadow, only I need a very thin border on bottom, not the shadow. I think that in android native is possible, but I cannot do it in Nativescript. I have tried differents solutions but I have not managed to do it.

Screenshoot of the shadow that I want to delete:
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OPdYJ.png)

Any idea/solution to accomplish my purpose?

Thank you

Comment: Are you using Angular for development? Generally we don't use Page element on Angular, your content will be injected into a Page and then added to Frame (page-router-outlet) by the framework. Also I'm not sure which shadow you are talking about, perhaps you could attach a screenshot?

Comment: @Manoj I have updated the question with a screen shoot and more code. I use "page" because I have  the cards plugin. Could you help me to delete the shadow? Thanks

Comment: You don't have to use a Page element just because you need card plugin, you are mixing up Angular and Core way of templating. With Angular you will register the card element and use it directly on your template.

Comment: @Manoj yes, you're right, I got confused reading the documentation, sorry, I have modified the code to delete the page tag, but this is not the main topic... I need to hide the shadow on tabs. Do you have any solution or tip to help me to accomplish this purpose?